# Have one text field passing input and upon clicking get the result into another textbox using servlets and html page

Tags: java, html, servlets

```
HTML page
```

upon clicking the calculate button,i need the answer to print in Answer text field, later i will write business logic, but first i want to check how it works,by passing some text, and upon clicking returning some text in answer field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name = 'calculate' action="Calculator" method ="get">
<h1>Text Based Calculator</h1>
<p>
    <label>Equation</label>
    <input type ="text" style="font-size:10pt;height:20px;width:400px;"
           id ="textEquation"/>
    <input type="submit" style="height:25px;width:200px" name="Calculate" value="Calculate"">


</p>
<lable>Answer</lable>
<input type = "text" style="font-size:10pt;height:20px;width:400px;"
       id = "textAnswer"/>
</body>
</html>


this is servlet class 

package textbasedcalculator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Calculator")
public class Calculator extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Calculator() {
        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String Equation = request.getParameter("textEquation");






        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In input tag use `name="textEquation"` instead if `id="textEquation"`. Then you can intercept this input value using getParameter() method. 
In Servlet, set this value intercepted as attribute in request and forward request back to jsp page.

```
 String equation = request.getParameter("textEquation");
request.setAttribute("answer",equation);
request.getRequestDispatcher("nameOfJspPage.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Now in forwarded jsp page add these lines:

```
<lable>Answer</lable>
<input type = "text" style="font-size:10pt;height:20px;width:400px;"
       id = "textAnswer" value="${requestScope.answer}"/>
```

Your answer will be displayed.
`Note:` your view must be jsp page not html page. You can not use html for dynamic content.
Hope this helps.